# How to add Textbox inside a table cell?

Tags: vba, automation, ms-word, cell

```
Sub t()

Dim File As String
File = "C:\Users\Tin\Desktop\a.docx"

Dim oWord As Word.Application
Set oWord = New Word.Application
Dim oDoc As Word.Document
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open(File)
oWord.Visible = True

With oDoc

Dim Table1 As Word.Table
Set Table1 = .Tables.Add(Range:=.Range, NumRows:=2, NumColumns:=2)

Table1.Borders(wdBorderTop).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
Table1.Borders(wdBorderRight).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
Table1.Borders(wdBorderBottom).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
Table1.Borders(wdBorderLeft).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
Table1.Borders(wdBorderHorizontal).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle
Table1.Borders(wdBorderVertical).LineStyle = wdLineStyleSingle

Table1.Rows.Height = 50

Dim lLeft As Long
Dim lTop As Long
Dim Rng As Word.Range

Set Rng = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range

Dim Shp As Word.Shape
  lLeft = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Information(wdHorizontalPositionRelativeToPage) + 50
  lTop = .Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Information(wdVerticalPositionRelativeToPage) + 20
  Debug.Print (lLeft)
  Debug.Print (lTop)

Set Shp = .Shapes.AddTextbox(Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, Left:=lLeft, _
    Top:=iTop, Width:=20, Height:=20, Anchor:=Rng)
End With

End Sub
```

I am automating Word in Excel.
I have tried to adjust the textbox location but failed. It always stays outside of the table.
I can automate it in Word itself but in Excel controlling Word Textbox seems "not understandable" to me when it comes to positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Even if this is an old question I wanted anyway to investigate it.  I tried your code (Excel macro with an added reference to the Word Object Library) and couldn't find something wrong with it.  **Your code works as expected, a square shape inside the first cell.**

I'm using Office 2010 (italian language).